# How to add a new record to datagridview control in Visual Basic?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, datagridview

I want to add to my site a simple table/excel-like feauture that will display some values. So, I added a gridview. I don't use Datasets or database biding at all. All I have is a small form with two entries. When the user clicks a button, I want to add some values to the datagridview control as a new row. How do I add a new record to datagridview control in VB.NET?

I have tried this code:

```
GridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {Value1, Value2})
```

but I get an error that:

> 'Add' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection'

My ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="731px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Grade" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can yuo please provide your aspx markup and code behind

Comment: my aspx:                                                                                       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="731px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Grade" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

Answer (score 0):

ok. use a datatable like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
     if(!IsPostback)
     {
         DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

         DataColumn myDataColumn; 

         myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
         myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
         myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Value1";
         myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

         myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
         myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
         myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Value2";
         myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);
         ViewState["Data"]=myDataTable;
     }
}


protected void btnAdd(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Datatable Dt=(Datatable)ViewState["Data"];
    DataRow Dr=Dt.NewRow();
    Dr[0]=TextBox1.Text;
    Dr[1]=TextBox2.Text;
    Dt.Rows.Add(Dr);
    ViewState["Data"]=Dt;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy. All you have to do is to Bind your grid to any Colleciton, such as List, Array, DataTable. Create your record class

```
Public Class MyRecord
    Private _name As String = ""
    Private _grade As Integer = ""

    Public Property Name() As String 
        Get   
            Return Me._name    
        End Get    
        Set(ByVal value As String)   
            Me._name = Value
        End Set   
    End Property

    Public Property Grade() As Integer
        Get   
            Return Me._grade 
        End Get    
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)   
            Me._grade = Value
        End Set   
    End Property

End Class
```

In your Page_Load Bind your grid to List

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPotback Then

        Dim list As New List(Of MyRecord)()
        list.Add(New MyRecord() With { _
                       Key .Name = "dsfsdf", _
                       Key .Grade = 45 _
        })
        list.Add(New MyRecord() With { _
                       Key .Name = "dsfsd234f", _
                       Key .Grade = 50 _
        })

        Session("MyList") = list
        GridView1.DataSource = list
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Then add some form with textboxes and button and handle button on_click event

```
Protected Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
    Dim list As New List(Of MyRecord)        

    If Session("MyList") Is Not Nothing Then
        list = DirectCast(Session("MyList"), List(Of MyRecord)) 
    End If

    list.Add(New MyRecord() With { _
                       Key .Name = txt1.Text, _
                       Key .Grade = Convert.ToInt32(txt2.Text) _
    })


    GridView1.DataSource = list 
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Sorry if there are any errors, I am a C# developer